# ScrollViewer catching PointerPressed + PointerMoved to scroll

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

I'm currently creating a little drawing program, and I've a white `Grid` inside a `ScrollViewer`.

To detect if user is drawing, I catch the `PointerPressed` event to set my variable `isUserDrawing` to true, and I catch the `PointerMove` event, and if `isUserDrawing` I do write a line where the mouse is.

It works very well with a standard mouse. But when I use the simulator to test it with touch, the `ScrollViewer` is catching events and start scrolling and the `Grid` is not anymore triggering events.
Is there anyway to make the `ScrollViewer` responding only with two fingers instead of one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your options are to either put something transparent on top of the ScrollViewer and grab input events off of that or not use a ScrollViewer at all. Either way - you will need to handle scrolling and zooming yourself.

Comment: Damn, I suppose I will have to recreate something like that.
I hope there is a easy way to do it.
I'm thinking about a Canvas Container and two scroll bar who move the Top/Left position of the grid inside.
But for the mouvement, I don't see how to handle it.

Comment: Well, if you use a canvas, then just handle manipulation delta events and update Canvas.X/Y positions by the delta from the events.

Comment: @FilipSkakun, what do you mean "handle scrolling and zooming yourself"? Maybe you have any useful sample? offtopic, sorry.

Comment: I don't have a sample I can share - you would basically need to handle manipulation events on another element and call `ScrollToVerticalOffset`/`ScrollToHorizontalOffset` or `ChangeView` if targeting Windows 8.1 to scroll to specific position. Another thing if you are targeting 8.1 is I think a new API for Windows 8.1 was you can enable `ManipulationMode` combined with `ManipulationMode.System` and then you get the events. Also use this API to cancel `ScrollViewer` scrolling. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.canceldirectmanipulations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
subitem.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a child control, you can set 
`Child.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;`
in this case the enents will not be bubbled to the scroll viewer. set
`Child.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.System;` for standard manipulations.